# Using MatchIt to match groups in a retrospective analysis

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, feature-selection, multiple-imputation, matching

I am interested in using the R package MatchIt to preprocess my data as to obtain matched groups based on a predefined treatment variable. However I am facing a few issues.

The first issue is that my data contains many covariates (approximately 80) in addition to the treatment variable. Many of these covariates have missing values, and it seems that MatchIt does not support missing variables. For those of you who have used MatchIt, what is your approach to solving this problem? Do you use imputation methods (e.g. the package `mice`) avoid NAs? Or do you perform variable selection to choose the most significant variables (e.g. lasso using `glmnet`) to do dimension reduction +/- imputation?

The second issue is that I have many observations (n = 23000) with about 200 in my treatment group and the remaining 22800 in my control group. In this situation which method in MatchIt would be best suited (also taking into consideration the other aspects of my data as I have described above)?

As always, many thanks for the help.

Comment: Doesn't `MatchIt` integrate well with `Amelia II` to do multiple imputation?

Comment: Remove the NA rows before passing the data to MatchIT... The real question is, why are the missing in the first place...?

Comment: The idea of matching using ~80 covariates that you are uncertain if they are relevant to the regression outcome seems like a over-matching mine-field. (I know I am 4 almost years late to the party but I say this for future reference.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *Matching* package instead in the following steps:

- Use any package (preferably the *MICE* package) to impute *n* complete data sets. You will need to impute at least 5 data sets.
- Extract *n* complete data sets from the imputation.
- Calculate a propensity score (for treatment) in each complete data set.
- Average the propensity score in all *n* data sets and use that to retrieve your matched cohort by using the *Matching* package, in which you can use externally obtained propensity scores for creating matched groups.

This is one of the alternatives for doing multiply imputed matching in R.